# Is it possible to define a new class within a t4 template?

Tags: t4

Is it possible to define a new class within a t4 template?

I tried this but it gave me an error 'A template containing a class feature must end with a class feature'

```
<#+
    public class AppSettingDefinition
    {
        private string _dataType;
        public string DataType
        {
            get { return _dataType; }
            set { _dataType = value; }
        }
    }
#>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes this is possible, the error I received was because I had text after class feature closing tag #>